# Deriving the Pollaczek - Khintchine formula

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I used this result in a paper a while back and now I want to be clear about where it comes from (I know it's correct). I wonder if someone could explain?

I have a moment generating function for an M/G/1 queue (ie Markovian, General, 1 server) of:

$\frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho h^*(s)}$

Where $\rho$ is the traffic intensity ($\rho=\lambda\mu$ where $\lambda$ is the poisson parameter - ie rate of arrivals and $\mu$ is the average service time)

While $h^*(s)=\frac{1-g^*(s)}{s\mu}$ - and $g^*(s)$ is a Laplace transform (into the domain of s) of a distribution function $g(x)$ for service times.

Now - so far, so standard - differentiating this and taking the negative of its value at $s=0$ should give us the expectation of waiting time in the queue.

The standard result for this differentiation (and negation) is $\frac{\rho\mu(1+c^2)}{2(1-\rho)}$, where $c$ is "the co-efficient of variation", namely the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean for service times.

Now this differentiation is laborious and I don't think I am getting it right - and I suspect it involves knowledge of what property is revealed by $\frac{dg^*(s)}{ds}$ - which I am not clear about.

I am happy to read a source if that's easier than an explanation but I would appreciate some pointers about how we get from $\frac{dg^*(s)}{ds}$ to $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $g^*(s)=E[e^{-sx}]$ and that the Taylor series for  $g^*(s)$ around $s=0$ is given by $g^*(s)=g^*(0)+\frac{\mathrm{d}g^*}{\mathrm{d}s}|_{s=0}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2g^*}{\mathrm{d}s^2}|_{s=0}+...$

It is a straightforward exercise to calculate the first few terms of the Taylor series of $g^*(s)$; $g^*(s)=1-\mu(s)+\frac{\mu^2(1+c^2)}{2}s^2 + O(s^3)$.

From this we get $h(s)=1-\frac{\mu s}{2}(1+c^2) + O(s^2)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}s}=\frac{-\mu}2(1+c^2)+O(s)$.

We know the Laplace-Stieltjes transform (or "moment generating function") $M(s)=\frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho h^*(s)}$ and, substituting in these series for $h^*$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}h^*}{\mathrm{d}s}$, we have that $\frac{\mathrm{d}M}{\mathrm{d}s}=\frac{\rho(\rho-1)\frac{\mathrm{d}h^*}{\mathrm{d}s}}{(1-\rho h)^2}$ can be approximated as $\frac{\mathrm{d}M}{\mathrm{d}s}=\frac{-\rho(1-\rho)\frac{\mu}{2}(1+c^2)+O(s)}{(1-\rho)^2+O(s)}$. When $s=0$ we can conclude that $\frac{\mathrm{d}M}{\mathrm{d}s}=\frac{-\rho\mu(1+c^2))}{2(1-\rho)}$.

Comment: Thank you. But on the Taylor expansion should it not be:
$g^*(s)=g^*(0) +\frac{dg^*}{ds}|_{s=0}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2g^*}{ds^2}|_{s=0}+...$ or have I missed something?

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention to the fact that $T_Q^*(s)=\frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho h^*(s)}$ is not the moment generating function. It is the Laplace (or Laplace-Stieltjes) transform.

I will use the notation that you suggested. $\lambda$ - arrival rate. $\mu$ - mean service time. But $\mu$ for mean service time is not a common notation for those who work in the field of queueing theory. $\mu$ usually stands for service rate.

Note that $c^2$ is the squared coefficient of variation, i.e. if $S$ denotes the service time random variable, then
$$
c^2 = {E(S-ES)^2 \over (ES)^2}={E(S^2)\over (ES)^2} -1
={E(S^2) \over \mu^2} -1.
$$
Then the quantity you are asking about, $E(T_Q)=\frac{\rho\mu(1+c^2)}{2(1-\rho)}$, which is the expected time the customer spends in the queue, is then equal to
$$
E(T_Q)=\frac{\rho\mu(1+c^2)}{2(1-\rho)}=
\frac{\rho\mu}{2(1-\rho)}{E(S^2)\over \mu^2}
={\lambda E(S^2) \over 2(1-\rho)}
={\lambda (g^*(s))''_{s=0} \over 2(1-\rho)}. 
$$
The last equality is due to the fact that $g^*(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}g(x)dx$ (you assume that $g(x)$ exists) and thus 
$(g^*(s))''_{s=0}=\int_0^\infty x^2 g(x)dx=E(S^2)$.

Now, since $T_Q^*(s)$ is the Laplace transform, then $(T_Q^*(s))'_{s=0}=-E(T_Q)$. Consider the euqation for $T_Q^*(s)$:
$$
T_Q^*(s)(1-\rho h^*(s))=1-\rho.
$$
Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $s$ and put $s=0$ and note that $T_Q^*(0)=h^*(0)=1$:
$$
\tag{1}
-E(T_Q)(1-\rho)-\rho (h^*(s))'_{s=0}=0.
$$
Now cosider the expression for $h^*(s)$:
$$
h^*(s) s \mu =1-g^*(s).
$$
Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $s$:
$$
(h^*(s))'_{s} s \mu + h^*(s) \mu =-(g^*(s))'_s.
$$
If you put now $s=0$ then $(h^*(s))'_{s=0}$ vanishes.
Differentiate once more:
$$
(h^*(s))''_{s} s \mu + 2 (h^*(s))'_{s} \mu =-(g^*(s))''_s.
$$
Now put $s=0$:
$$
\tag{2}
(h^*(s))'_{s=0}  =-{(g^*(s))''_{s=0} \over 2 \mu}.
$$

Combine (1) and (2) and you will get the expression for $E(T_Q)$.

Comment: Thank you. But I think you should take up your points about what is or is not a moment generating function and the notation with D. R. Cox (see p242 of the 1977 edition of "The Theory of Stochastic Processes" for instance) :-)

Comment: I am not in the position to discuss the opinion of prof. Cox, which he has expressed in his excellent book. But the moment generating function, say $M(s)$, of the function $\mu(x)$ and the Laplace transform, say $L(s)$, of $\mu(x)$ are related by $L(s)=M(-s)$. And these functions are completely different! In the context that we are discussing here $T^*_Q(s)$ is NOT a moment generating function.